# Does the form of a hysteresis curve depend on the magnetic field change rate?

Tags: electromagnetism

I have given some people access to a Monte Carlo program that I created to simulate ferrofluids. They adapted it in order to simulate hysteresis loops. I had warned that Metropolis algorithm can only provide expected values of physical quantities for systems in thermal equilibrium. That means that a certain value of magnetic field **B** will provide a single value for magnetization **M**. That is to say that it only represents para- or superparamagnetic behaviour for a model of spheres with fixed magnetic moment magnitude.

I had also told them that they could note some kind of hysteresis curve if they changed the magnetic field before the system reached thermal equilibrium, but that I didn't know how to link that to reality. They actually did so and note very nice hysteresis curves that looks pretty similar to experimenta hysteresis curves.

The problem is that the observed remanence depends on how many Monte Carlo steps the program takes to change a given \Delta{B}. They showed me those results and I opined they could possibly interpreted it by relating a given amount of MC steps to a \Delta{t}. However, by doing that we would be admitting that the time taken to change B by a certain amount changes the value of the remanent and coercive fields.

Does that happens in experiment? Or is the hysteresis curve always the same, with no regards to how fast the field varies?

Comment: I am not an expert on this but I do know that temperature certainly does affect the shape (i.e., slopes) of the curves.  I would imagine that in the extreme limits, the temperature would also affect the saturation levels.  Similarly, if one applied a strong enough external field I would imagine this would affect the curve since it could affect the internal magnetization of the material.  However, I am not sure how radical the $\Delta B$ would need to be in order to do this...

Comment: The steps in a Monte Carlo program are usually not time steps. There are temporal effects in magnetic materials, but for most materials I know they are related to conductivity and skin effect. Iron powder cores that suppress skin effect can work at hundreds of MHz and there are ferrite materials  that work in the GHz range, so the magnetic relaxation time scale has to be on the order of sub-ns. Usually it's more important to treat magnetic elements with quasi-static Maxwell than with time dependent magnetism. A known counterexample would be YIG-oscillators. IMHO yours is a numerical problem.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Temperature effects in thermally equilibrated systems is what Metropolis algorithm represents well. My problem is about time. No pun intended.

Comment: @CuriousOne Surely, MC steps are not time steps, but there are some tricks to relate them in some MC methods. It's certain that a hysteresis curve will never be observed for dipolar hard sphere model through Metropolis algorithm if the system is allowed to converge to thermal equilibrium in each B value. The trick of the simulation I described was changing B before the system reaches equilibrium. Otherwise, a superparamagnetic curve, with no hysteresis, is obtained.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro: I don't know what trick you would use. If you are interested in time dependent magnetism, then you would have to solve the equations for spins, which, in case of the electron spin, would require simulation on the ps-timescale. Unless you do this properly, you are not simulating the system. Like I said, I suspect a numerical problem, but I have never done numerics on magnetic systems, so I don't know how close you are to even being in the ballpark.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm talking about simulation of ferrofluids that treats the nanoparticles as _macrospins_. Bulk magnetization inside each nanoparticle is kept constant with no reference to or description of individual spins. Take a look at this paper: http://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.86.011403

Comment: I don't see why the magnetic relaxation timescale in nano-particles should be significantly slower than the timescale on which spins rotate in strong local fields. Does the paper give any hint to why that's supposedly the case?

Comment: @CuriousOne To be honest, I read only the abstract of that paper. But, in the context of "colloidal magnetic particles", a distinction between "Néel relaxation" and "Brownian relaxation" is made. Brownian relaxation is related to physical rotation of the nanoparticles themselves in a solvent liquid. _Vide_: http://www.seniorscientific.com/technology/nanomagnetic-relaxometry/neel-vs-brownian/ and https://www.researchgate.net/post/Neels_and_Brownian_relaxation_time_depends_upon_frequency

Comment: I see, they basically assume that the magnetization is fixed to the particles' shape, which would make sense if the field isn't too strong. That I can believe and in that case the timescale should be orders of magnitude slower than in the solids.

Comment: @CuriousOne Besides, as colloidal magnetic particles can be displaced by means of magnetic field gradients, a simulation may focus on the nanoparticles positions instead of their magnetic moments. Also, one might not be interested in the evolution of single nanoparticles, but in how the density of nanoparticles change. Or in how the overall colloidal system magnetic moment changes. For that, _exact_ rotational and translational trajectories of individual particles are not necessary, as long as they follow a realistic tendence as a group.

Comment: So you are running a mean field model on the behavior of these particles? I think I am beginning to understand better what you are modeling... but I have next to no intuition how clusters of such particles will behave.  Sounds like there could be a lot of microscopic structure formation going on (aren't these particles forming linear clusters?) that might be hard to capture with a mean field.

Comment: @CuriousOne Now that I think of it, the field must be weak enough to not destroy the ferromagnetic monodomain structure inside the nanoparticles, but strong enough to make they rotate physically in the solvent. I've just found this thesis: "Rotational Relaxation Dynamics of Ferrofluid Systems" (Sonia May) - http://www.dcf.ds.mpg.de/fileadmin/mitarbeiter/Sonia_Utermann/publications/050131_Rotational_relaxation_dynamics_of_ferrofluid_systems.pdf

Comment: @CuriousOne With regard to the structures formed by the nanoparticles, David Tomanek made some 3D animations of chains of magnetic nanoparticles in colloidal dispersion (ferrofluids). Here is: http://www.pa.msu.edu/cmp/csc/simulferrofl.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34837/discussion-between-leonardo-castro-and-curiousone).